# Applicative functors pure matching not wrapped

Tags: haskell, applicative

I'm learning about applicative functors.  In the [source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-656) for an applicative `Maybe`, the `pure` function looks like this:

```
instance Applicative Maybe where
    pure = Just
    ...etc
```

With the arguments expanded, I think it looks like:

```
pure x = Just x
```

When I call `pure (Just 5)`, it returns `Just 5`.

Shouldn't it return `Just (Just 5)`?

Similarly, for [List](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-739):

```
instance Applicative [] where  
    pure x = [x]
```

When I call `pure [4,5,6]` it returns `[4,5,6]`.

From the signature, it looks like `pure [4,5,6]` should return `[[4,5,6]]`.

Can someone explain in simple terms what's happening here?

---

Wait, I think I got it - since there's no context provided, `pure [4,5,6]` is not using the `Applicative` for `List`, it's just using the general case and returning the same value.  Is this correct?

Comment: Try `pure 3` and `(pure :: Maybe Int -> Maybe (Maybe Int)) $Just 3`. I think it's using the general case, and as [ghci tries to default to IO](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html), `pure (Just 5)` is evaluated as `IO (Maybe Int)`.

Comment: The type of pure is *not* `m a -> m (m a)` - so there is nothing to say that if the value `x` in `pure x` is already inside an `m`, that the `m` which pure creates would be the same `m`. As @Yosh stated, typing `pure ..` into the GHCi prompt will default the type of pure to `a -> IO a` - if it weren't for defaulting this would produce an ambiguous type error when you tried to print it (as e.g. `pure ()` has type `Applicative f => f ()`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pure` is an overloaded function. It takes a value of any type `a`, and wraps it up into an applicative functor `f`.

```
ghci> :t pure
pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a
```

`f` is determined by the context. If you're passing `pure x` into a function which expects a `Maybe`, the type-checker will infer `f ~ Maybe` and select `Maybe`'s instance of `Applicative` and `pure x` will evaluate to `Just x`. Likewise, if you pass `pure x` into a function of lists, the type-checker will use `[]`'s instance of `Applicative` and `pure x` will return a singleton list.

```
ghci> :t map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]  -- map is a list function
ghci> map (+1) (pure 4)        -- so when we pass in (pure 4)
[5]                            -- it means a singleton list
```

In your case, I'm guessing that you're typing `pure x` at a GHCI prompt. If you don't provide any context (such as applying a list function to `pure x`), GHCI will default to assuming you meant to use `IO`'s instance of `Applicative`, for which `pure x` is a do-nothing `IO` action returning `x`. GHCI then dutifully executes that `IO` action.

```
ghci> pure 'a'
'a'
ghci> pure (Just 3)
Just 3
```

If the type-checker can't *see* the context based on your code, you can declare the context manually using a type annotation.

```
ghci> pure "hello" :: Maybe String
Just "hello"
ghci> pure (Just 3) :: Maybe (Maybe Int)
Just (Just 3)
ghci> pure [1,2,3] :: [[Int]]
[[1,2,3]]
```

Comment: Correct presumption re: GHCI prompt, I should have mentioned that. Interesting that it takes the IO context, that was the part I was missing.  Thank you!